# Return one specific data

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, xml

I would like to specifically return one data from xml.

If nameOfBusiness = Restaurant then it returns all the ratings (the three restaurants) with an itemname that has Restaurant.

How can I make it only alert one Restaurant and not including the other 2 Restaurant(with Steams and Origins)?

Here is my xml:

```
<resultitem>
 <itemname>Restaurant</itemname>
 <rating>3</rating>
</resultitem>
<resultitem>
 <itemname>Restaurant Origins</itemname>
 <rating>4</rating>
</resultitem>
<resultitem>
 <itemname>Restaurant Steams</itemname>
 <rating>4.1</rating>
</resultitem>
```

Here is my ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'someURL.xml',
  dataType: 'xml',
  success: function(xml) {
    var found = $(xml).find('resultitem itemname:contains("' + nameOfBusiness + '")');
    if (!found.length) {
      alert("Rating not published yet");
      return;
    }
    found.each(function() {
      var rating = $(this).parent().find('rating').text();
      alert("The rating for " + nameOfBusiness + " is " + rating);
    })
  }
});
```

Comment: instead of  `found.each` loop just process first item `found[0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For just the first item, you can use:

```
const foundRating = found.first().parent().find('rating').text();
```

You can also `break` out of the loop by returning `false`:

```
found.each(function(i, v) {
    if (i === 0) {
        var rating = $(this).parent().find('rating').text();
        alert("The rating for " + nameOfBusiness + " is " + rating);
        return false;
    }
});
```

[jQuery `each` docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

Comment: I also want to know, how can I have elements where I use contain on the <itemname>? I have <itemaddress> but I forgot to include it it the xml. Is Is something like.... find('resultitem itemname:contains("' + nameOfBusiness + '") itemaddress:contains("'+addressOfBusiness+'")')

Comment: There isn't a CSS selector for verifying text value, but you can do something like `$('itemname').map(function(i,v) {return $(v).text()});` (this works in browser but not in JSbin).  JSbin required another function like this: `var text = $('itemname').map(function(i,v) {return $(v).text()}); text = $.makeArray(text);`